# ipad application memory warning when using little memory

Tags: ipad, memory-management

I am running an ipad application compiled for release and am seing memory warnings once in a while.

When I run the app on the device and connect Instruments, I see that the app never passes 40MB of real memory, but the warnings are still occurring.

What might be causing this? How can I better track down the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

40 MB of real memory is a lot, for an iPad. Even if it was not, the system will deliver the low-memory warning to you from time to time anyway, without your application being the main culprit. Tracking down precise memory usage in your application is sometimes hard, I’d suggest to spend some time with the Object Allocation instrument while working with the app. If you are not getting killed and you are sure that you do not leak the memory, you can also simply ignore the warnings.

Comment: As far as I can see, I am staying put between 35 and 40MB. Even if the number was double, yet constant, I don't see why this should cause a memory warning?

Comment: You don't get all the memory available on the machine, the system will really start pestering you once you cross ~30 MB.

Comment: Keep in mind it is a warning... Think of the OS saying "Hey man, looks like you are starting to use a lot of memory, it would be really nice if you could clean up some things you aren't using. If not, cool I will let it go, but 3 strikes and you are out" (3 strikes meaning memory warning level = 3, at least from my experience)

Answer (score 1):

40MB is high for the iPad considering it only has 256MB to start with. There could be other applications holding on to memory which will be killed off as more memory is needed. Just make sure you aren't leaking anything. Also use NSAutoReleasePools where applicable to reduce peak memory usage in memory intensive loops.